# How do I set up a vertical list of "a links" buttons with space and custom lengths?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on designing a website and I'm running into issues with formatting around list items connected with links. If you run the code through the browser it'll show the site of where I am right now. I want the "Buttons" to move away from each other so it's a nice vertical display of them rather than overlapping each other. Also I've been trying to figure out how to adjust the width of the borders so all three buttons are the same width.

Also I've been trying to make the border colors change when the mouse hovers over it but none of the answers from other related posts on Stack Overflow have worked for me.

```css
/* Global Layout Set-up */
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;*/
  color: #fff;
  background: #384047;
}
/* Link Styles */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #39add1;
}
a:hover {
  color: #7dc9e1;
}

.container {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 80%;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 60%;
    background: #dfdfdf;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
}

.nav {
    max-width: 110px;
    min-width: 55px;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 100px;;
    background: #222;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 50%;   
}

.box p {
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7dc9e1;
}

a:hover {
    color: #39add1;
    border-color: #39add1;
}

.nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#welcome a{
    border: solid #7dc9e1; 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#s-in a{
    border: solid #7dc9e1; 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#s-up a{
    border: solid #7dc9e1; 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing Site</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
  <link href="#googlefont"></head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Testing Site</h1>
            <h4>demo website</h4>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li id="welcome"><a href="#">WELCOME</a></li>
                    <li id="s-in"><a href="#">SIGN IN</a></li>
                    <li id="s-up"><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of changes you'll want to make.

1. Add `display: block` to your `a` element, to ensure that the
   anchor takes up the full width of the list.
2. Adjust your `margin-top` values for your respective IDs so that the
   spacing is consistent as the above change causes a dramatic
   alteration.

That will get you a stacked navigation, though the borders aren't overlapping so you will see thick borders between each navigation.  To address your final concern about having the borders change color on hover:

`#your-id a:hover { border-color: #ff0000; }`

While not related to your question, a lot of your CSS could be cleaned up to avoid redundancies.  If all of the anchors in your list have a padding of 10px for example, it's probably better to do `.nav a { padding: 10px; }` than to state the padding for each unique ID.

Comment: This really helps! I actually have one more issue. I want the buttons to stay under the title as if they were part of the same element. I tried putting them together but the title above it is always out of format. What do you suggest?

Comment: I would have to see an example of what you're trying to achieve, to better understand how you would adjust your CSS.

Comment: Like if you go to the Pandora mobile website it'll show a button to download the app directly under the title. On my website I want to build a similar format with the buttons in a "fixed position" relative to the title. The issue is that the buttons move around the title when the page is resized. I want them to behave like they're part of the same section rather than moving around eachother.

Comment: One question per question please. Comments are not the place to ask more questions. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pls refer the updated css code and this what you expected

```
.nav {
        width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;  
}

.nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav li a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the display property of the "a" elements to "block" i.e. "display: block", the anchors will occupy the full width of the list.
    E.g.

```
list element1
list element2
list element3
```

Then, by using id values, set margin-top property to provide appropriate vertical spacing

Finally, in order to change the border color on hover, use below code

```
a:hover {
    border-color: (color of your choice);
}
```